# What should I use here, fit or suit?

Tags: british-english, adverbs

I have a sentence and two options which can be used here, what it the right one and why? Thank you!

«Heidi used to be in the girlband Atomic Kitten but she left because she never quite ________ in»

fit in
or
suit in

Answer (score 1):

**Fit in** is the right answer.

> Google dictionary definition: fit in – be socially compatible with
>   other members of a group.